# How to check whether a type exists (regardless of its size) with CMake?

Tags: build, cmake

When writing CMake platform checks, we can write

```
check_type_size("my_type" SIZEOF_MY_TYPE)
```

and determine the size of `my_type`. But what if the type doesn't exist at all? What about checking whether the type exists or not? How is that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `check_type_size()` also encompasses this functionality. In addition to setting the specified variable to the appropriate size, the command will also create an existence indication, e.g.

```
check_type_size("my_type" SIZEOF_MY_TYPE)
```

will set the variable `HAVE_my_type` according to whether or not the type exists, and, in fact, set `SIZEOF_MY_TYPE` to an empty string instead of 0 if the type doesn't exist.

More details in the [official documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CheckTypeSize.html).